# MySQL column with non-null values from other two columns

Tags: mysql

I would need to know if it is possible to do this in MySQL. Having a table like this:

```
| ID | Column1 | Column2|
+-----------------------+
|  1 |     1   |   null |
|  2 |    null |     2  |
|  3 |     3   |   null |
```

Get a column that combines column1 and column2 :

```
| ID | Column3 |
+--------------+
|  1 |     1   |
|  2 |     2   |   
|  3 |     3   |
```

so the logic would be for each row, if column1 has value different from null, column 3 would be that value, if not, would be value in column 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Look for case ... when

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `coalesce` to get the first non-null value of your columns

```
select id, coalesce(column1, column2) as column3
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

USE if null

```
 SELECT ID, IFNULL(Column1,Column2) AS Column3 FROM TABLE;
```

if column1 is null then use column2

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE

```
select id, case when column1 is null then column2 
               when column2 is null the comumn1  end as column3
```

from your_table

if null

```
select id, ifnull( column1 , column2 )  as column3 
from your_table
```

or coalesce

```
select id, coalesce( column1 , column2 )  as column3 
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired output by using coalesce() or ifnull() functions:

```
select id, coalesce(column1, column2) as column3 from yourtable
```

Note: the above expression will return null, if both columns are null. If both columns are not null, then the value from column1 is used.